# Warning message in R package 'Formula'

Tags: r, rstudio, warnings

When using `Formula()` or `as.Formula()` from the [Formula package](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/Formula/index.html), I get a warning message. It does not appear to affect functionality, but I have not been able to understand the source of it.

I am using the `Formula` package to update multipart formulas (for `ivreg()` in the `AER` package, but that is unrelated to the problem). After using `Formula()` or `as.Formula()` on a `formula` object, the next line of code that I run produces a warning message. I have been through the documentation and [GitHub repo](https://github.com/cran/Formula) but cannot understand the source of it.

```
library(Formula)
f1 <- y ~ x1 + x2 | z1 + z2 + z3
F1 <- Formula(f1)
class(F1)
```

```
> class(F1)
[1] "Formula" "formula"
Warning message:
In is.name(callee) && length(object) > 20 :
  'length(x) = 2 > 1' in coercion to 'logical(1)'
```

To be clear, it is not `class(F1)` specifically that produces this warning. For example:

```
> F1 <- Formula(f1)
> print("lol")
[1] "lol"
Warning message:
In is.name(callee) && length(object) > 20 :
  'length(x) = 2 > 1' in coercion to 'logical(1)'
```

I have emailed the package author.

The problem appears unrelated to other packages:

```
> (.packages())
[1] "stats"     "graphics"  "grDevices" "utils"     "datasets"  "methods"   "base"
```

However, the warning message is not reproduced in RGui, so it might have to do with RStudio(?)

Comment: This is not reproducible for me. Have you tried this in a plain R session without other packages attached? Specifically, the code `is.name(callee) && length(object) > 20` that triggers the warning does not seem to be from base R or from `Formula`...at least I couldn't find it with a quick search.

Comment: Thank you! I've tried installing it again and running withouth other packages loaded (except defaults) but I still get the same warning. However, the warning is not returned when doing it in RGui instead of RStudio.

Comment: OK, thanks, that helped. The problem comes from `.rs.sanitizeCall()`. It does not seem critical but I would recommend reporting it to RStudio. I've also added the `rstudio` tag.

Comment: @AchimZeileis, how did you work that out? Respect!

Comment: Given that the problem only occured in RStudio, it was natural to suspect that the error occurs somewhere in `tools:rstudio`. I used `options(warn = 2)` to turn the warning into an error and then used `traceback()` after triggering the problem. This showed the call stack with which I could quickly pin down the problem. See also the answer I posted now which explains more of the details.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The warning is triggered in the following way: When an object is created in RStudio, the `.rs.describeObject()` function from `tools:rstudio` is triggered to obtain information about the object. Among other things this uses the `.rs.sanitizeCall()` function which contains the following line:

```
long <- is.name(callee) && length(object) > 20
```

Thus, this assumes that `length()` returns a single number which, unfortunately, is not the case for `Formula()` objects:

```
f <- Formula(y ~ x | z)
length(f)
## [1] 1 2
```

So there isn't anything that the `Formula` package could do to avoid the warning - other than breaking the behavior of its `length()` method which has been in place for almost 1.5 decades.

In hindsight it was probably not the best decision to make the `length()` method behave this way. This even made it to the official `?length` documentation in base R:

> **Warning:**
>
> Package authors have written methods that return a result of
> length other than one ('Formula') and that return a vector of type
> 'double' ('Matrix'), even with non-integer values (earlier
> versions of 'sets').  Where a single double value is returned that
> can be represented as an integer it is returned as a length-one
> integer vector.

One way to avoid this issue would be to use

```
`length(object)[1L] > 20`
```

or

```
`any(length(object) > 20)`
```

in `.rs.sanitizeCall()`. I would recommend reporting this to the RStudio developers.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time. I have posted the issue to the rstudio community. Hopefully they will pick it up https://community.rstudio.com/t/warning-in-rs-sanitizecall/151957

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to report and repost it!

Comment: Stumbled upon the same problem. I filed an issue on rstudio github repository https://github.com/rstudio/rstudio/issues/12409 linking to this answer and community repost.

Comment: Cheers, and great that you mention the proper channels for reporting stuff like this ^^